# Possible to use a function inside of a different classes __construct?

Tags: php, function, class, pdo

EDIT:::

So I have classes that I would like to work together. My first two establish a connection to the database:

dbconn.php

```
<?php

class dbconn {
    protected $dbname;
    protected $dbuser;
    protected $dbpassword;
    protected $dbhost;
    protected $connection;

    public function __construct($dbhost, $dbname, $dbuser, $dbpass) 
    {
        $this->dbname = $dbname;
        $this->dbhost = $dbhost;
        $this->dbuser = $dbuser;
        $this->dbpass = $dbpass;
        $this->connect();
    }

    public function getConnection()
    {
        return $this->connection;
    }

    protected function connect()
    {
        $this->connection = new PDO("mysql:host={$this->dbhost};dbname={$this->dbname}", $this->dbuser, $this->dbpass);
    }
}
?>
```

dblogin.php

```
<?php

$db = new DBconn('localhost','phpproject','carl','pdt1848?')

?>
```

My other class is trying to edit items from the database. I tried to link the db connection classes throught the __construct of this class, I'm just going about this all wrong apparently. 
editbeers.php

```
<?php

class BeerEditor
{
    protected $dbconn;

    function __construct($dbconn){
        $this->dbconn = $dbconn;
    }

    function addBeer(Beer $beerObj){
        //making connection to db here
        $conn = $this->dbconn->getConnection();

        $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO beers (beer_name, beer_type, beer_abv, beer_rating) VALUES (:beer_name, :beer_type, :beer_abv, :beer_rating)");

        $stmt->bindParam(':beer_name', $beerObj->getBeerName());
        $stmt->bindParam(':beer_type', $beerObj->getBeerType());
        $stmt->bindParam(':beer_abv', $beerObj->getBeerABV());
        $stmt->bindParam(':beer_rating', $beerObj->getBeerRating());

        $result = $stmt->execute();

        if($result === false){
            var_dump($conn->errorCode());
        }

        return $result;
    }

    function listBeers(){

        $conn = $this->dbconn->getConnection();
        $result = $conn->query('SELECT * FROM beers');

        $result->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS|PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE, 'beers');
        $beers = $result->fetchAll();

        return $beers;
    }


}
?>
```

Comment: The error is very specific. it says $dbconn is not defined. Where is it supposed to come from?

Comment: The variable `$dbconn` in your class is private to your class. The variable `$dbconn` in your page is an entirely different variable. You need to give it a value _in your page_ in order to pass it into your class. You can't rely on the variable in your class providing the value to pass into your class to be assigned to the variable in your class which provides the value to be passed into your class...

Answer (score 1):

1. In the second file you've quoted you never actually create `$dbconn`. If you think it should be created somewhere within `/home/carlton/public_html/PHPproject/allincludes.php` then you should probably double-check that.
2. Your constructor could check to see if the information passed to it is somehow valid before allowing it to be stored.

Answer (score 0):

Because `$dbconn` is undefined and not an database connection object you are not able to call the method `getConnection()`.

When creating BeerEditor you need to pass in a database connection object.

```
$BeerEditor= new BeerEditor($dbconn);
```

Comment: i think $dbconn is supposed to be a reference to a database object that has the method getConnection().  That class probably creates a mysqli or pdo connection

Comment: @Jacob yes you are right. I'm going to edit the original post to include my dbconn.php class. I can't figure out how to get them to work together.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps the $dbconn var is defined somewhere in your required file.
Try

```
var_dump($dbconn);
```

after the require and see if it is the object you expect.